# content of body is overwriting the footer

Tags: html, css

I am using html to make pages that I need to print later. Every page has a fixed footer. It happens that the body content is overlapping the footer. The body content should not lose information for the next page.

By the searchs I made, the footer is less important than the body. I tried putting and ID on the footer but it did not solve the problem.

```css
@media print {
  #footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 1000px);
  }
}

#container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  min-height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0 2em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

</head>
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:100%">page header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <hr style="color:#000080" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>

            <td colspan="4"><br>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
  </tfoot>



  <tbody id="container">
    <tr>
      <td>


        <div>
          <p>
            my text is here and much longeur, i just can't copy it here, you can try a longer text to see

          </p>

        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>



</table>

<table border="0" id="footer" width="100%">
  <tr>

    <td width="100%">
      footer text
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all you are missing a `<body>` tag as far as i can see. To your question: You might use a container `<div>` around your contents (except the footer), give this a bottom padding of the height of the footer and make the footer overlap this bottom part of the container. It should do this automatically, but you could also give it `z-Index: 999;` or whatever.

Comment: there's no changes :(

Comment: I made the text longer and the body wasn't overlapping the footer. What browser are you using and are you sure the problem is also coming up in your code snippet? On a sidenote, making layouts with tables is VERY outdated, unless you're using the code in E-Mails. Maybe they are the source of the problem, aswell.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all: There are **many** errors in your HTML. There are parts of which i don't even understand what they're supposed to do. I can't fix all of this now, sorry. And why are you using tables at all? Layouting with tables is weird. Did you design this in Word and export it as HTML?

So in the following, i **only** fixed you footer problem. It doesn't have to be `position: fixed;` and `display: block;`. Actually, for printing it doesn't make sense to fix the position of anything to the screen.

I hope this helps anyway...

```css
@media print {
  #footer {
    height: calc(100vh - 1000px);
  }
}

#container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  min-height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0 2em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

</head>
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:100%">page header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <hr style="color:#000080" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>

            <td colspan="4"><br>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
  </tfoot>



  <tbody id="container">
    <tr>
      <td>


        <div>
          <p>
            long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>
                long text<br>

          </p>

        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>



</table>

<table border="0" id="footer" width="100%">
  <tr>

    <td width="100%">
      footer text
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

</html>
```

Comment: than's for your answer, in this case the footer is displayed in the last page, it should be fixed in every page !

Comment: What do you mean by "every page"?

Comment: my text inside <p> is very long so it's should be displayed continuously in other pages without losing lines or something, i need to print this page later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a sticky footer check below snippet. Here i set the #footer's `height` as 20px and #container's `padding-bottom` as same 20px. So it will not hide any content.

```css
#footer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  min-height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0 2em;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:100%">page header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <hr style="color:#000080" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><br>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody id="container">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <p>
            my text is here and much longeur, i just can't copy it here, you can try a longer text to see
          </p>
          <p>
            my text is here and much longeur, i just can't copy it here, you can try a longer text to see
          </p>
          <p>
            my text is here and much longeur, i just can't copy it here, you can try a longer text to see
          </p>
          <p>
            my text is here and much longeur, i just can't copy it here, you can try a longer text to see
          </p>
          <p>
            my text is here and much longeur, i just can't copy it here, you can try a longer text to see
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" id="footer" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      footer text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very mych for your answer. Unfortunately, when I try this with my real text, the last line on the first page is hidden by the footer (lose information) how can I avoid this situation?

Comment: you can check the hidden line by removing :  background-color: #ccc; from #footer

Comment: @AbdelhadiBenazout no you are not suppose to remove `background-color`, then it will be overlapping

Comment: make sure you footer's height and container's padding-bottom are same. then surely it won't hide anything.